# Spring Batch job fails with FatalStepExecutionException : JobRepository failure forcing rollback

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm getting below error message while the job is running. But its not happening at regular interval. The job is running successfully one day and fails on another day.

Any assistance would help.

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException: JobRepository failure forcing rollback
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:463)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, can you also give your code that led to this exception. It's hard to do anything with just the error.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, edit the question add code there instead. Can you share your job configuration (reader, processor , writer, listeners and not only the datasource) as well as the *full* stacktrace please?

Comment: Were u able to solve this issue? I am also facing the same issue.